# How to roll up branches to their master in R

Tags: r

I am working with a dataset in R programming where there is a Branch and a Branch_Link. Each Branch is a unique value and contains all of the Branch_Link values as well. Whenever a Branch is not a Master_Branch, it has a Branch_Link that it ties back to. However, not all Branch_Links are Master_Branch's so we would have to loop through the Branch_Links and see if that Branch_Link, within the Branch column has a Branch_Link tied to it. When there are no Branch_Link values to tie back to we would know that is the highest level or Master_Branch.

[In the picture within this link, The orange columns are the initial columns I have to work with. The light blue columns would be generated be a loop most likely. And the Yellow column, Master Branch would be the value at the highest Branch_Link_X](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X6jut.png)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.